# JavaFX ImageView fits container

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, pane

I'm trying to fit an ImageView in an AnchorPane, the ImageView is obtained from a database, so no CSS, I tried binding the width and height of the ImageView withe the width and height of the AnchorPane, but I get this result:

[image: anchorPane problem]

Here's my fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
       <AnchorPane style="-fx-background-color: grey;" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
           <children>
               <Label fx:id="nombrePlato" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxHeight="50.0" prefHeight="50.0" text="Nombre del Plato" textAlignment="CENTER" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                   <font>
                       <Font size="30.0" />
                   </font>
               </Label>
           </children>
       </AnchorPane>
       <AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPane" layoutY="300.0" styleClass="anchorPane" stylesheets="@../../../../core/resources/css/MainCSS.css" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="50.0">
         <children>
            <ImageView fx:id="imagenPlato" fitHeight="100.0" fitWidth="100.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And here's my method:

```
public void rellenar(Label nombrePlato, ImageView imagenPlato, Plato plato, AnchorPane anchorPane) throws SQLException {

        nombrePlato.setText(plato.getNombre());
        Blob blob = plato.getRutaImagen();
        int blobLength = (int) blob.length();
        byte[] blobAsBytes = blob.getBytes(1, blobLength);
        Image convertToJavaFXImage = convertToJavaFXImage(blobAsBytes, 1024, 768);
        imagenPlato.setImage(convertToJavaFXImage);

        imagenPlato.fitWidthProperty().bind(anchorPane.widthProperty());
        imagenPlato.fitHeightProperty().bind(anchorPane.heightProperty());
    }
```

Any idea how to make it fit he anchorPane and make it responsive?

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to an ImageView, you could use a [CSS `-fx-background-image` attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region) on a Region (such as your AnchorPane).  The [CSS `-fx-background-size`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background-size) option will provide you with various sizing alternatives such as cover or contain:

> *contain*
>
> Scale the image, while preserving its intrinsic aspect ratio (if any),
>   to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit
>   inside the background positioning area.
>
> *cover*
>
> Scale the image, while preserving its intrinsic aspect ratio (if any),
>   to the smallest size such that both its width and its height can
>   completely cover the background positioning area.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem most likely lies in the following line:

```
<ImageView fx:id="imagenPlato" fitHeight="100.0" fitWidth="100.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
```

Specifically, you've set:

```
preserveRatio="true"
```

...which will try to keep the aspect ratio the same, so the image won't fill the container. Set it to `false` instead, and you should be good to go.

Comment: The problem is with the Images that  have more height than width, they become smushed if I put it to false.

Comment: @Green_Sam I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do - you have to choose whether you want the image to preserve its aspect ratio, or fill the container. You can't have both!

Answer (score 3):

Grab `ImageViewPane` class from [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/secure/attachment/40455/ImageViewPane.java) as referenced from this [bug ticket](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091789) and place inside project.

Then wrap your image view in your FXML as so:

```xml
<?import PATH.TO.CLASS.ImageViewPane?>

<ImageViewPane fx:id="imageViewPane">
  <imageView>
    <ImageView fx:id="imageView"
               pickOnBounds="true"
               preserveRatio="true">
    </ImageView>
  </imageView>
</ImageViewPane>
```

The problem is `ImageView` only has `fitWidth`/`fitHeight` properties which do not conform to the parent's size or preferred size.  `ImageViewPane` wraps `ImageView` in a pane and updates the `ImageView`'s `fitWidth`/`fitHeight` properties to the pane's size.

Comment: Weird class that doesn't exist in regular JavaFX. Useless

Comment: @parsecer What is useless?

Comment: ImageViewPane, it's not part of JavaFX

Comment: @parsecer that doesn't make it useless or weird