# Javafx resize ImageView to AnchorPane

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, resize

I have an ImageView inside an AnchorPane and I want to resize the Image in the same proposition as the AnchorPane resize.

Can someone explain me how to do that?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can bind the image view's `fitWidth` and `fitHeight` properties to the width and height of the anchor pane:

```
imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(anchorPane.widthProperty());
imageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(anchorPane.heightProperty());
```

If you also want to preserve the proportions of the image you are displaying, you can do

```
imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
```

Comment: Depending on the scene you may also need to set the `managed` property of `imageView` to `false` to prevent it from influencing `min` and `pref` sizes of the `AnchorPane`.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not working the way I want. I want to keep the distances to sides of the AnchorPane. So if there is a distance to the bottom if the Pane of 30px and I resize the Pane I want to scale the button to keep the 30px distance. Is that possible?

Comment: @Bashfire What button? You hadn't mentioned a button before. You probably need to post a [MCVE] to demonstrate what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry I use the ImageView as Button, but this doesn't matter, so it's just a normal ImageView.

Comment: Just do `imageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(anchorPane.heightProperty().subtract(30))`? (Replace `30` with whatever you need). Or just wrap the image view in another pane - say a `StackPane` and place the `StackPane` in the `AnchorPane` (then bind to the stack pane's width and height).

Answer (score 0):

Only thing work for me.
On the view, listen change of the AnchorPane and set ImageView Size

```
init {
   myAnchorPane.widthProperty().addListener { observable, oldValue, newValue ->
            myImageView.fitWidth = myAnchorPane.width
            myImageView.fitHeight = 0.0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65853658/918858).  Basically you can use the `ImageViewPane` that you can include in your project.